# english.yoda.stackexchange.com belongs on this question does

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

Why has the "belongs on" message changed to Yoda speak?

> - english.meta.stackexchange.com belongs on
> - ell.stackexchange.com belongs on

[image]

Comment: Perhaps because their part of the world hadn't yet ticked over to the second of April.

Comment: @Lawrence weren't the jokes going to be opt-in because of the coronavirus? I thought I read that one meta or in one of those blog posts.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica Sorry, I haven’t been keeping up with the announcements.

Comment: *On english.meta.stackexchange.com belongs* the more comprehensible formulation would have been, as Yoda-speak word order OSV is.